Does AOSP support font alises? If so, how/where are these defined?
As https://superuser.com/revisions/1512700/2 explains, Windows supports this functionality:

Font substitution is set via the registry under the FontSubstitutes registry key at:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes


Likewise, almost all desktop-focused Linux-based OSes do, with fc-alias. As an example, on my Fedora 40 KDE Spin installation:
fc-match monospace
fc-match sans-serif
fc-match serif

returns

NotoSansMono-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans Mono" "Regular"
NotoSans-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans" "Regular"
NotoSerif-Regular.ttf: "Noto Serif" "Regular"


However, I see absolutely no information online regarding whether the AOSP supports this functionality, nor how. Irrespective, I've reason to believe that support might exist, because when I view an HTML message via the official GMail, Outlook, and Proton Mail e-mail client applications with text content set to monospace, the typeface utilized appears to be monospace, and consistent across the clients.

Related: How do I fix monospace fonts once and for all? and Why has Android made it impossible to install system fonts?
